# ssh reverse tunnel listens always to localhost

Tags: networking, unix, ssh, tunnel

I use the following command to set up a reverse tunnel:

```
ssh -i dev.pem -vvv -R 8480:localhost:8080 user@host.com "sleep 6000"
```

What ends up happening is that ssh starts to listen to the lo device, rather than on the eth0 device (binds to 127.0.0.1 instead of the remove public ip).

Any clues how this behavior can be altered?

Comment: whati f you say `*:8480` ?

Answer (score 10):

Enable GatewayPorts in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

Reference: http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/ssh-port-forwarding